# importing multiple scss files not working in express app

Tags: sass

I am using node-sass-middleware and so far i had one scss file and it was working just fine. Now created another scss file and using the second file link on top the first file using this.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .quizes-container {
    justify-content: space-between;
    .card {
      width: 32.5%;
    }
  }
  .quiz-container-title {
    div {
      padding-right: 1em;
    }
  }
}
```

and imported like this `@use 'media_queries'`;

However in my .css output the codes from the second file is not showing at all.

I am really confused.

Comment: Can you add some content of your `media_queries` scss file?

Comment: @media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  .quizes-container {
    justify-content: space-between;
    .card {
      width: 32.5%;
    }
  }
.quiz-container-title {

  div {
      padding-right: 1em;
  }
}
}

Answer (score 0):

SCSS files need to be imported using the `@import` keyword.

```
@import "media_queries";
```

Answer (score 0):

[node-sass-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass-middleware) uses [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) for compiling sass to css, However `node-sass` is deprecated.

> Warning: LibSass and Node Sass are deprecated. While they will
> continue to receive maintenance releases indefinitely, there are no
> plans to add additional features or compatibility with any new CSS or
> Sass features. Projects that still use it should move onto Dart Sass.

and even `node-sass-middleware` is dead (I think) because there is no activity and no new releases.
[Github Open Question](https://github.com/sass/node-sass-middleware/issues/137)

If you want to continue with this then you need to use old `@import` syntax, the new syntax `@use` will not work.

```
@import "media_queries";
```

Or switch to new [Dart Sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass)

Implementing `node-sass-middleware` with new dart sass, use this [gist](https://gist.github.com/sameerthekhans/3eb1a4f83b3c39b03e91c8fc0110d889#file-node-sass-middleware-with-dart-sass), create new file (`sass-middleware`) and add the content to newly created file, then import it like this, then you are good to go.

```js
/*index.js*/

//const sassMiddleware = require('node-sass-middleware');
const sassMiddleware = require('./sass-middleware');
```

Note: That gist I have created is a copy of `node-sass-middleware` but with new dart sass implementation, So all credit goes to `node-sass-middleware`